# Built-in mail application is not localized on a multi-language Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, email, localization, multilingual

I have a fresh install of the English version of Windows 8.1. Two users are configured : one uses the English UI, the other uses the French UI. I also got the Office French language pack configured accordingly for each user.

But the built-in mail application (the one that you get by clicking on the tile on the home screen) is still in English for the user that uses French everywhere.

I went to hotmail.com and configured the language to French for that user. Hotmail UI on the web is in French. I rebooted the computer (just to be sure) but the mail client is still in English for that user.

The account using French is a *child account*, created on the computer with the new user wizard. A new Hotmail email was created in the process.

How can change the locale of the built-in Windows 8.1 built-in mail client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted write a comment, but my reputation score is low. 
Is it other build-in application in French?

Open the `Control Panel` -> `Clock, Language, and Region` -> `Language`
And check `Windows display language`.

[image]

In you case should be so:

- English `Windows display language:` **Available**
- French `Windows display language:` **Enabled**

Then open `Change data, time or number formats` and change language in `Location` tap.
And finally, try change language in `Language in non-Unicode programs` on `Administrative` tab.

Maybe, [this tutorial](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/5853-display-language-change-windows-8-a.html) help you.

Comment: I did not try that, I will (tonight). Welcome to SuperUser!